# How to enable Node editing in full mode?

Tags: nodes

Is there a way to expose selected node fields so that they are directly editable when the node is being viewed?

I want visitors of my site to be able to type some context into a text area, select relevant taxonomy terms etc. In other words, to do what you would normally be able to do in node-edit mode.
My node is also a Commerce product display. I need the users to input their data, also select their relevant product information and submit all on the same page.

I installed the [Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/edit) module, but I couldn't find how to expose the fields for editing.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a module which can enable this functionality - [Editablefields](https://drupal.org/project/Editablefields).

Module page says itself --

> This module allows CCK fields to be edited on a node's display (e.g.
>   at node/123), not just on the node edit pages (e.g. node/123/edit). It
>   also works within views etc. Anywhere a 'formatter' can be selected,
>   you can select editable (or click to edit).

I have used this module for edit fields at views not at node, but I am sure you can achieve your requirement.

Comment: Thanks. It works but it has limitations. It doesn't expose the title for one